# Ember Js: Getting Uncaught RangeError when calling Component

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I've created a simple route and component. I'm trying to call component from the template. But when i call, component is called recursively and getting the below error

```
vendor.js:58853 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Class.init (vendor.js:58853:20)
    at Class.superWrapper [as init] (vendor.js:33826:20)
    at Class.superFunction [as _super] (vendor.js:29300:20)
    at Class.init (vendor.js:56183:19)
    at Class.superWrapper (vendor.js:33826:20)
    at Class.superFunction [as _super] (vendor.js:29300:20)
    at Class.init (vendor.js:55450:19)
    at Class.superWrapper (vendor.js:33826:20)
    at Class.superFunction [as _super] (vendor.js:29300:20)
    at Class.init (vendor.js:54600:19)
```

Template.hbs contains the below

```
{{settings/admin-settings}}
```

modified the router.js as

```
this.route('admin-settings', { path: 'admin-configuration/admin-settings'}); ;
```

I didn't added anything to route.js and component.js

Comment: hello! can you add your ember-source version, as well as the content of settings/admin-settings? (the component) thanks!

Comment: Hi @NullVoxPopuli, the Ember version is 1.13.15. And the controller contains     
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
initialActions: function() {
        console.log('From Controller');
 }.on('init')
});

And one more thing, the project already contains a lot of components, Calling some other components from agent-settings/template.hbs is working fine

Comment: It is out of support since a couple of years. The error you are facing _may_ indicate an endless loop. Maybe related to transitions. At least that would be my first guess in recent Ember versions. You are using a _very_ old version of Ember. v1.13 was released in 2015 (sic!). Not sure if at that time an error in rendering engine (not Glimmer VM yet) could cause an endless loop as well.

Comment: I recall back then you could hit this pretty easily if you injected controllers onto other controllers in a cyclical manner